# Create a /tmp partition that uses filesystem type of tmpfs in kickstart?

Tags: centos, redhat, partition, pxe-boot, tmpfs

I'm writing a [kickstart](https://docs.centos.org/en-US/centos/install-guide/Kickstart2/) script to use when PXE booting to automatically configure new systems with basic settings. I've got everything working except for the partitioning of the boot drive: my `/tmp` directory is under my `/` (root) partition instead of a dedicated `tmpfs` partition. I've found [this support article](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/4598541) on the topic, but it's locked behind a paywall.

This is what I have so far for partitioning in my kickstart script:

```
part /boot --fstype=xfs --size=1024 --ondisk=vda
part pv.01 --fstype=lvmpv --size=1 --grow --ondisk=vda

volgroup myvg --pesize=4096 pv.01
logvol swap --vgname=myvg --fstype=swap --recommended --name=swap
logvol / --vgname=myvg --fstype=xfs --grow --size=1024 --name=root
```

And this is the output of `df` that it results in:

```
Filesystem             Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs               1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs                  1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                  1.9G  8.6M  1.9G   1% /run
tmpfs                  1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/myvg-root   17G  1.5G   15G  10% /
/dev/vda1              976M  144M  766M  16% /boot
tmpfs                  379M     0  379M   0% /run/user/1000
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution was unrelated to partitioning. The option to mount `/tmp` as a `tmpfs` is actually handled by the systemd unit file `tmp.mount`, so it can be enabled in a kickstart script by enabling `tmp.mount` in the post install script:

```
# Run post-install configuration
%post --interpreter=/usr/bin/bash --erroronfail --log=/var/log/kickstart-post.log
systemctl enable tmp.mount
%end
```

Which results in this `df` output after boot:

```
Filesystem             Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs               1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs                  1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                  1.9G  8.6M  1.9G   1% /run
tmpfs                  1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/myvg-root   17G  1.5G   15G  10% /
tmpfs                  1.9G  8.0K  1.9G   1% /tmp
/dev/vda1              976M  144M  766M  16% /boot
tmpfs                  379M     0  379M   0% /run/user/1000
```

This is essentially the inverse of the process [documented on the archlinux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Tmpfs#Disable_automatic_mount) for disabling this feature.

More info is available on the archlinux wiki, but an important thing to note is that if another partition is already mounted at `/tmp` then this unit will have no effect, even if it is enabled.

Related reading on the pros/cons of putting `/tmp` on a `tmpfs` here: https://access.redhat.com/discussions/688183